# Question Python Group by and Apply function

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, apply

I have a data set like below:

```
idx start_date end_date flag 
1.    6-17-20.  6-24-20.  1
2.    6-17-20.  6-24-20.  0
3.    6-17-20.  6-24-20.  1
4.    6-17-20.  6-24-20.  0
1.    6-25-20.  7-03-20.  1
2.    6-25-20.  7-03-20.  1
3.    6-25-20.  7-03-20.  1
4.    6-25-20.  7-03-20.  1
```

What I want is

```
idx start_date end_date flag   idx1 idx2 idx3 idx4
1.    6-17-20.  6-24-20.  1.   1      0.  1.   0
2.    6-17-20.  6-24-20.  0.   1      0.  1.   0
3.    6-17-20.  6-24-20.  1    1      0.  1.   0
4.    6-17-20.  6-24-20.  0    1      0.  1.   0
1.    6-25-20.  7-03-20.  1    1      1.  1.   1
2.    6-25-20.  7-03-20.  1    1      1.  1.   1
3.    6-25-20.  7-03-20.  1    1      1.  1.   1
4.    6-25-20.  7-03-20.  1    1      1.  1.   1
```

I knew I can do for loop use group by but I want to ask if there is efficient way to do it?
I just need to group by and do long to wide transformation. After that append all the dataset and merge to the original one.

Comment: Another possible option is `table = collections.defaultdict(list)`.  For each key/value pair you can then call `table[key].append(value)`.  When done, you're then free to look at the keys in the table in any order you want (sorted or otherwise), and to handle the values however you want.

Comment: How do you compute idx? Year and day?

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be clearer but I think I sort of understand what you are trying to achieve. Do comment if I am mistaken!

I'm presuming that you want the start and end dates as row entries and the columns of `idx`s indicating which IDs have those start and end dates. With that assumption in mind, here is how it can be done:

```py
### Filter out only those with flag == 1
df_new = df[df['flag'] == 1].copy()

### Consolidate unique start, end dates. Aggregate the corresponding ids as lists
ser_wide = df_new.groupby(['start_date', 'end_date'])['idx'].apply(list)

### Convert the previous lists into binary lists of the same length
unique_ids = sorted(df_new['idx'].unique())
ser_wide = ser_wide.apply(lambda idxs: [(1 if idx in idxs else 0) for idx in unique_ids])

### Define new column names
idx_cols = [f'idx{int(i)}' for i in unique_ids]

### Convert into dataframe
df_wide = pd.DataFrame(ser_wide.to_list(), columns=idx_cols, index=ser_wide.index)
df_wide.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(df_wide)
  start_date  end_date  idx1  idx2  idx3  idx4
0   6-17-20.  6-24-20.     1     0     1     0
1   6-25-20.  7-03-20.     1     1     1     1
```

Hope this achieves what I think you intended.